# What's wrong with infinite loops inside loop()?

Tags: arduino-uno, loop

I wanted to run the following code as something similar to Tone or pwm. However for some reason that I am unable to seek it doesn't work.

```
#define WAIT 3200UL

void setup() {
  DDRB |= B00000001;  // set pin8 as output
}

void loop() {
  unsigned long t;
  while (1) {

    PORTB &= B11111110; // clear pin 8
    
    for (t = 0 ; t < WAIT; t++);

    PORTB |= B00000001; // set pin 8
    
    for (t = 0; t < WAIT; t++);


    //            PORTB &= B11111110;
    //            delayMicroseconds(WAIT);
    //            PORTB |= B00000001;
    //            delayMicroseconds(WAIT);

  }
}
```

the code is pretty simple, just toggling a pin. If I use the commented section, it works fine but as is, it doesn't work.

I removed the "while(1)" statement since it was unnecessary for now, it started to work improperly, (changing the WAIT didn't have any effect and I'm not sure I'm getting a full swing).

Pin 8 is connected to an LED + R to ground and a piezzo in parallel to them. the LED seems to be steady on yet the buzzer makes a low noise. I measured a   voltage of 3.8v DC and arround 9v AC on the pin, other pins I ran the code for were similar.

As another attempt I put a Serial.print in the beginning of the while(1) but it printed out only once.

Also looked at the assembly code generated for a clue to find out what does delayMicroseconds() do but couldn't figure out what's wrong.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Answering your title - there's nothing wrong with an infinite loop within loop, but it's not necessary as loop itself is an infinite loop. Move unsigned long t; into setup and you will have an infinite loop without needing to explicitly code the while(1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I will give you some unsolicited advise about your coding style.
Instead of writing:

```
PORTB &= B11111110;
...
PORTB |= B00000001;
```

you could write:

```
PORTB &= ~_BV(PB0);
...
PORTB |= _BV(PB0);
```

These are standard AVR idioms, and they make it clearer that you are
toggling the pin PB0.

Then, to answer your actual question, your delay loop does not work
because it got optimized-out by the compiler. This has already been said
in Michel Keijzers' answer, but let me elaborate.

All modern compilers are *optimizing* compilers. This means they can
change your code in whatever way they see fit, as long as the *visible
effects* remain the same. The effects considered *visible* are usually
I/O and access to variables declared `volatile`. Quite importantly, the
*slowness* of the program is *not* considered a visible effect for the
purpose of optimization. And if you think about it, it makes good sense:
if the slowness of the program were to be preserved, then any form of
optimization would be impossible. Thus, a loop that has no effect other
than slowing your program down can legitimately be optimized-out.

The solution to your problem is quite simple: if you want a delay, then
call `delayMicroseconds()`. Or maybe even `delay()` if you are OK with
its low resolution. On the other hand, if you need sub-microsecond
resolution, you can call `_delay_us()`, from the avr-libc. This function
(or rather, macro) provides single-cycle resolution. If you write

```
#include <util/delay.h>

...
_delay_us(1.375);
```

you get *exactly* what you ask for, i.e. a delay of 22 CPU cycles
(on an Arduino Uno clocked at 16 MHz). The issues with this
function are that it is AVR-specific, and its argument must be a
compile-time constant.

It has been suggested to you to write your delay loop using a `volatile`
loop counter. I strongly advise you *against* doing that, for three
reasons:

1. Doing so will force the counter to be allocated to RAM, thus
   consuming a scarce and valuable resource for no good reason.
2. Incrementing a RAM-based 32-bit counter takes 20 CPU cycles. Add
   to this the time required to test the end-of-loop condition and you
   will realize that your delay resolution is way worse than that of
   `delayMicroseconds()`.
3. Your actual delay will depend on the clock frequency, and probably
   also on the compiler's version, making your code pretty fragile.

Comment: Upvoted for the (much extra) explanation

Comment: Re, "effects considered visible are usually I/O and..."  There is no I/O in the C++ programming language.  The effects that are considered visible are calls to functions with external linkage, and access to `volatile` functions.  When a C++ program does something like `std::cout<<"hello world!\n";`, that's a call to an external library function.

Comment: `static` loop counter should work just as good in this particular case, saving some of the load/store instructions.

Comment: @jameslarge: Recent versions of the Arduino IDE pass the `-flto` option to the compiler, which triggers full-program link-time optimization. In this case, external linkage is irrelevant, and calls to external functions _can_ be optimized out (yes, I tried).

Comment: @wondra: I tried with a `static` counter, both a global static and a local static. In both cases the loop got optimized-out, although the counter did get written with its end-of-loop value.

Comment: @EdgarBonet work for me using VisualStudio, seems that such construct mgiht be even more dangerous than initially expected. Another reason to use the delay from avr lib.

Comment: Oops!  I meant, ...access to volatile _variables_.

Answer (score 1):

First

```
t = WAIT;
for (t = 0; t < WAIT; t++);
```

The first statement is not useful, since t will be assigned to 0 in the for loop.

However, since t is not used, probably it is optimized and removed by the compiler, meaning it will not perform a delay.

You should make t volatile. This prevents the compiler from optimizing it (out).

The only difference with or without the infinite loop is that variable t does not need to be allocated for (and keeps its value from the previous loop), but since the value is overwritten it does not make a difference.

Comment: Even t is marked volatile, the loop will execute that quickly you won't even see it flickering.

Comment: increasing the WAIT value might help ... not sure how many clock cycle are used. I would say 16 MHz / number of clock cycle for one iteration handling.

Comment: And a useful device to analyze this is a logic analyzer, you can buy it for 5 euro from China and is easier to use for low signal checking than a (cheap) oscilloscope.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but `t` is used(read) in the `t < WAIT` expression and both written&read in the `t++` expression. The fact that the statement of the `for` cycle is empty might make it target to compiler optimization for another reason, but it does not appear to me that `t` is unused.

Comment: it is not used afterwards and has no side effects, so the compiler can optimize it away.

Comment: Incrementing, comparing and jump is just a single digit of instructions. At max (65535) this is around 600000 tics, so 600000/16000000 = 37ms. So it SHOULD be a noticable flickering.

Comment: @Kwasmich why is 65535 the same as 600000  tics and not 65535 tics? Than it would be 3,7 ms and because in the example 32000 is used it would be appr. 2 ms or less which is probably unnoticable.

Comment: 65535 loop iterations times single digit count of ticks (10 or less) is roughly 600000 (rounded for convinience), yes, 3200 is a pretty low delay.

Comment: I commented out the t=wait which was silly and  was left from a while(t--) ; structure but it's still the same, also I already had tried many different values to fall in a sensible range but still doesn't work. I guess the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Check the time before/after a loop and see if it is optimized out (you can even put an extra for loop to check longer times).

Comment: @MichelKeijzers OK thanks! defining t as volatile solved the problem. but I'm still in doubt like the comment by @wondra  so I wrote it as `for(t = 0; t < WAIT;) t++;` but still the compiler ignore it unless defined as volatile. what exactly is using afterwards as @kwasmich also mentioned?

Comment: Probably what he meant is (and I put in my answer), is that when using volatile, you prevent the compiler to ignore the for statement. That is why it works with volatile and not works without volatile.